# Azure pyspark visualization causes interpreter crash

Tags: azure, matplotlib, pyspark

I've been trying to make a simple visualization within Azure Jupiter notebook, but each time I execute matplotlib function the kernel crashes. I am using pyspark3 kernel.

Here are the lines of code, which cause the interpreter crash.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.hist([1,2,3])
```

And the error message: 
[image]

Any idea, how to enable the plotting feature on Azure server?

==Edit===

If I use suggested magic, in the very first cell, I see the following error:

```
unknown magic command 'matplotlib'
UnknownMagic: unknown magic command 'matplotlib'
```

Then the execution of *plt.hist()* raises following exception:

```
"UnknownMagic: unknown magic command 'matplotlib'
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".
```

Comment: I've just updated the question.  The magic that you suggested doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: So the problem seems to be that the backend is set to some Qt backend, which is not useful because you cannot start any Qt application on your server. You will need to find a way to tell matplotlib to use the inline backend. However, I don't know how to do that if IPython is not available.